# Does 'git cherry' consider the number of commits in head and upstream?

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario:

```
$ git branch –a 
* dev
  master

$ git branch --contains 53fdfaf89fca499c36c71d29f25eb1a13b32d4d6
 dev

$ git branch --contains f7dfb3689edcaf5f819fa5e691ce13abf858bca8
   dev
   master

$ git cherry master dev
+ 53fdfaf89fca499c36c71d29f25eb1a13b32d4d6
+ a4e66dbde954f73185d61bfb78b40ac5e61fe56c
+ 6fcffbd9b57e8a74726ea2cd3713f14baaaa06f5
+ 5031ad3cdf2e81c880e9cbf049abed6f1edde3bc
+ dcca33c373df6953ff164e8d70531abd71841278
```

But the twist is, the commit `f7dfb3689edcaf5f819fa5e691ce13abf858bca8` is actually cherry picked from `53fdfaf89fca499c36c71d29f25eb1a13b32d4d6`, and both are exactly the same (pardon me since for some reason we had to have 2 exact same commits with different commit id) Other than the commit message and the commit id, there is no difference between the two commits.

Now as per `git cherry` documentation,
*The commits are compared with their patch id, obtained from the git patch-id program.*

So I actually went ahead and executed the `git patch-id` program as below

```
$ git show 53fdfaf89fca499c36c71d29f25eb1a13b32d4d6 | git patch-id
bd6c061bd6c380d53832510cbaf68bebb4fb182d 53fdfaf89fca499c36c71d29f25eb1a13b32d4d6

$ git show f7dfb3689edcaf5f819fa5e691ce13abf858bca8 | git patch-id
bd6c061bd6c380d53832510cbaf68bebb4fb182d f7dfb3689edcaf5f819fa5e691ce13abf858bca8
```

The above result shows that `git patch-id` actually does recognize the two commits to be same but still the `git cherry` command fails to do that.

The only reason I can see for this to happen is if `git cherry` takes into account some factor other than `git patch-id`.

Does it consider the number of commits made on the head (i.e. dev branch in my case)? Since we have 2 versions of the commit on the dev branch and only 1 on master.

Comment: It should work even for multiple instances. Just tested locally and it did work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From your output above, you have merged the cherry-picked revision into dev as well (by merging master at some point).  Git is walking through the set of revisions, it now finds an exact match and removes it from the set of revisions to be examined, and doesn't generate a patch id for it.  The good news is that `git merge` still recognizes the original change on dev is already in master, and doesn't attempt to re-apply that change.

I think in most workflows involving cherry-picking, you never merge the branch containing the cherry pick back into your branch.  You'd typically do something more like: commit the fix to master, and then cherry-pick to a stable branch.  Or, in your case, commit the bug fix to master, and then merge master into dev.

You can see the code behind `git cherry` [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/889d35899ba64640e47798681ecb34a4be043bad/builtin/log.c#L1466).  Take note of the patch id generation [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/889d35899ba64640e47798681ecb34a4be043bad/builtin/log.c#L699).  In particular, note the [comment on line 719](https://github.com/git/git/blob/889d35899ba64640e47798681ecb34a4be043bad/builtin/log.c#L719).  It's going to ask for revisions on master than are not in dev, which will be none since master is merged into dev.  So no patch ids are generated.  As a result, it looks like your original non-cherry-picked revision hasn't been brought over to master.

You could argue the behavior is a bug.  But fixing it, I think, may have substantial performance hit.